# Showing carousel in modal window and ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm not even sure if I'm on right way with this and I'm very new in ajax/jquery stuff.

What I trying is to load on one page 20 thumbnails from category. When user click on the thumb it is showed in full size on modal. Then I want user to be able to see next image from that category.

Now when I click on image it just showing empty popup and no errors in console.

So this is where I show images from the category

```
        // some other code here
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_album = ? ORDER BY image_id ASC LIMIT 24");
$result -> bindParam(1, $album_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();
echo '
   <div id="gallery" class="section-scroll main-section">
      <section id="gallery-wrapper" class="">       
         <div class="gallery-content three-columns">';
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++)
    {
        echo '            
            <a class="mix category-2 open-overlay" href="ajax-gallery.php" >
            <img width="1000" height="600" src="images/gallery/'.$row['image_name'].'" data-src="images/gallery/'.$row['image_name'].'"/>
                <div class="hidden-xs">
                    <div>
                        <span><h3>Full size</h3></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>';
    }
        // some more code
```

Then in `ajax-gallery.php` I have

```
if(!empty($_POST["album_id"]) && !empty($_POST["image_id"])) {

$album_id = $_POST['album_id'];            
$image = $_POST['image_id'];

    $value = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_album = ? ORDER BY image_id = ? ASC');
    $value->bindParam(1, $album_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $value->bindParam(2, $image_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $value->execute();
    $result = $value->fetch();    

    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        echo '
        <section id="gallery">
            <div class="gallery-content fullscreen"><a class="close-button"><i class="icon-close"></i></a>
                <div class="gallery">
                    <div class="loading-spinner"></div>
                    <div id="images" class="owl-carousel">
                        <div class="item"><figure><img src="images/gallery/'.$row['image_name'].'" /></figure></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>      
        ';
    }
```

HTML in the echo in `ajax-gallery.php` is the carousel when user click on thumbnail.

This is js part and I'm sure it is wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#gallery, #a').click(function() {
   $.post('ajax-gallery.php',
        {
            "album_id": $(this).attr('album_id'),
            "image_id": $(this).attr('image_id')
        },
        function (response) {

        });
 });
});
```

Update:

This is when you point on the thumb
[image]

Comment: And you are sure the path of the image is correct?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure. I that my mistake is in ajax part and where I pass album_id and image_id and the response from `ajax-gallery.php`.

Comment: If I put few images in `ajax-gallery.php` without any php .. just html they are visible in the modal carousel.

Comment: Can you post the HTML code where the click event is performed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be to append those values to the url "ajax-gallery.php?album_id=your_album_id&image_id=your_image_id"

After appending the variabels to the url you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#gallery .mix category-2').click(function() {
      var url = $(this).attr('href')
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
     })
     .done(function(data) {
        console.log("success");
     })
     .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
     })
   })
})
```

In this way you will get the variabels in ajax-gallery.php.
Probably you have to do "$_GET["album_id"]" I didn't test it so let me know. Good Luck with your work!

Comment: The returnet response from your query is in the "data" response. Look at this in your console and do something with it!!

Comment: I will try to explain to you what is going on: fist you must change the returned response from ajax-gallery.php. You are actually wrapping the data returned from your query in a foreach loop and in the loop you are echoing the results. This is not the way ajax expects his response. You need to return an array of results and then echo json_encode($results). This array will be passed to youa ajax response in the 'data' parameter and then you can output the returned values to your gallery. I can not change here all your code fir you. I'll be glad to help you but you also need to help yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post the HTML code where the click event is performed? You are also referencing to an element with an Id of "a", are you also sure about this or you want to reference to an anchor tag `<a>`. Also has to be checked if you really have an attribute with the name as "image_id" which I doubt.
So to recap, post the html code where you perform the click action so I can help you.

Comment: Hey, clicking is on first portion of code ... `<a class="mix category-2 open-overlay" href="ajax-gallery.php" >`..

Comment: Posted image on the question. When point to the thumb you see `Full Size` and you can click on it..

Comment: Ok @jordan, than is as I was thinking. The error is in your ajax call. You DON'T HAVE any attribute "album_id" and "image_id" in the anchor tag you are referencing with $(this).attr('album_id').

Comment: One option could be  to append those values to the url "ajax-gallery.php?album_id=your_album_id&image_id=your_image_id"

Comment: I have edited my first answwer! See the edited code here above in the second answer I gave you